# MapInfo tab files with LargeInt can't be converted to QGIS or any other format

Tags: qgis, gdal, mapinfo, tab

I am trying to convert a MapInfo tab file with ogr2ogr

I did this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" testing.shp TEST.tab
```

And get this error;

```
ERROR 3: Failed to parse field definition at line 8 in file TEST.tab

    FAILURE:
    
    Unable to open datasource `TEST.tab' with the following drivers
    oid LargeInt ;
```

QGIS gives me this error when adding a vector layer:

```
Invalid Data Source: C:\Temp\Struer\TEST.TAB is not a valid or recognized data source.
```

I tried this:

```
Change the LargeInt to Integer in MapInfo.
```

Then it works fine.

So it seems like there is a problem with the LargeInt type.

Is it GDAL that can't handle this or does anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: I don't think ESRI Shapefiles support 64-bit integers.

Comment: can ogrinfo read your mapinfo  file when you have a largeint?

Comment: @nmtoken no the ogrinfo also fails
ERROR 3: Failed to parse field definition at line 8 in file test.tab
ERROR 3: Failed to parse field definition at line 8 in file test.tab
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `test.tab' with the following drivers.

Comment: @Taras, no i thing the problem lays in the mitab

Answer (score 3):

There is a GDAL plugin available [here](https://www.pbinsight.com/support/product-downloads/item/mapinfo-efal-sdk-download) that adds support for the Extended MapInfo TAB format.

Comment: Link is sadly dead

Comment: Is this the new version of the link?:
https://support.precisely.com/product-downloads/item/mapinfo-efal-sdk-download/

Comment: Yes, that's the new version of the link. Precisely now develops MapInfo Pro and the EFAL SDK and GDAL Driver.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL's mitab module indeed does not know about the `LargeInt` type.

Until that support has been added to GDAL, you have to use a different type.

Comment: Hmm.
The LargeInt type has been in Mapinfo since approximately 2009, how can it be added to mitab module

Answer (score 0):

This will be available in GDAL 3.7.0 (May 2023) per https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/7165.